# unbind, вложенный в bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#solo img').bind({
    mouseover: function() {
        for (i = 1; i <= $(this).attr('id'); i++) {
            $('#' + i).attr('src', '../../images/stars/star_gold.png')
        }
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        for (i = 1; i <= $(this).attr('id'); i++) {
            $('#' + i).attr('src', '../../images/stars/star.png')
        }
    },
    click: function() {
        $('#solo img').unbind('mouseout')
    }
});
```

1). Почему не срабатывает событие `click`?

2). Если я хочу написать 3 функции для `click` - мне их через запятую писать?

Comment: `click` прекрасно работает: [пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3c6rev4/).

Answer (score 1):

0) Метод [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) устарел, используйте [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Если у вас его нет, обновите jquery.

1) [Всё работает](http://jsfiddle.net/d3c6rev4/1/)

2) И `bind`, и `on` принимают только по одному обработчику. Вызывайте их столько раз, сколько у вас обработчиков и по очереди навешивайте